# I don't find way to process <content:encoded> tag with python and etree from lxml library

Tags: python, xml, rss, lxml, elementtree

I'm working process xml files to a rss provider. I found a problem when I tried process compound tags, like that I show in the code below, `<dc:creator>, and <content:encoded>`.

Well, I searched on web a solution for this and I found a solution. In the head of document appears a tag with info about the rss file, with a tag. In this tag I saw the attribute `xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"`, so, I used it to find the text in creator tag, some like this:

From:

`creator = node.find('dc:creator').text #Doesn't work.`

to

`creator = node.find('{http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/}creator').text #Work !`

Well, so far so good, but when I try do the same with the tag `<content:encoded>` this doesn't work, and I don't understand why.
In the rss tag there are a attribute : `xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"` but if I do the same, this doesn't work.

I'm sure that the object  was loaded perfectly, but i don't understand why haven't the "text" method  like in the other case.

`content = node.find('{http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/}encoded').text`

The error that I see is:

```
 File "eTree.py", line 30, in parseXML
    content = node.find('{http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/}encoded').text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Any idea?

A minimal version of xml documents is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
<channel>  
  <item>
    <title><![CDATA[Yo, Juan Carlos]]></title>        
    <dc:creator><![CDATA[Javier Ayuso]]></dc:creator>    
    <content:encoded><![CDATA[<p>Los peores momentos de mi reinado.</p>]]></content:encoded>      
  </item>  
</channel>
</rss>
```

Comment: Post simplified XML that we can use to reproduce the problem. Otherwise, one can only guess

Comment: Yes, of course. Thanks.

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem, this is the complete working code used for testing : http://ctrlv.it/python/2065/387134282

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end the problem wasn't in the processing, I was working well. My big fail was that I did not check correctly the file. I only wrote a little part of the entire of .xml in the question here, but is an enormous file , and I just found out that a few items `<item></item>` haven't the tag `<content:encoded>` inside, because of this the find method not return a object with a "text" attribute. My way to process and the way using the namespaces are correct both.
Now I changed the code and I check if the object exist before entering the "text" attribute, and this work perfectly.

```
    if node.find('content:encoded',ns) is not None:
        contenido = node.find('content:encoded',ns).text
```

Thanks you so much for all the answers.

Answer (score 2):

As documented in [Parsing XML with Namespaces](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml-with-namespaces) you can try passing a dictionary of the namespaces to `find()`/`findall()`/`iterfind()` and this will enable you to use the namespace as a prefix for the element's name like this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
<channel>  
  <item>
    <title><![CDATA[Yo, Juan Carlos]]></title>        
    <dc:creator><![CDATA[Javier Ayuso]]></dc:creator>    
    <content:encoded><![CDATA[<p>Los peores momentos de mi reinado.</p>]]></content:encoded>      
  </item>  
</channel>
</rss>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
# the namespaces contained in this document
ns = {'dc': 'http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/',
      'content': 'http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/'}

node = root.find('channel/item')
print(node.find('dc:creator', ns).text)        # N.B. pass namespaces to find()
print(node.find('content:encoded', ns).text)

# These also work...
print(node.find('{http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/}creator').text)
print(node.find('{http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/}encoded').text)
```

**Output**

```
Javier Ayuso
<p>Los peores momentos de mi reinado.</p>
Javier Ayuso
<p>Los peores momentos de mi reinado.</p>
```

Comment: Thanks you for the answer, finally the problem wasn't the way to process, just the existence of the object.

Comment: Right. so passing the namespace dictionary to `find()` had nothing to do with it?? That's what you've added in your answer, in addition to checking for `None`.